# split a string into a unique list - refactor this

Tags: c#, string, refactoring

Ok, this looks ugly :) What is a good way to refactor this block of code?

`Users` is data which is entered on the screen, and for this example we want distinct result in the `_someDTOObject.Users`

```
string[] userNames = Users.Split(new char[] { ',' });
string tempUserStr = "";
foreach (string user in userNames)
{
    tempUserStr += user.Trim().ToUpper() + ",";
}

userNames = tempUserStr.Split(new char[] { ',' });
var uniqueUsers = userNames.Distinct().ToList();

foreach (string user in uniqueUsers)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
    {
        _someDTOObject.Users += user + ",";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Why are you splitting, then joining, then splitting again?

Comment: @JonSkeet - appears to address his 'distinct' requirement.

Comment: @EBarr: No, the call to `Distinct()` does that...

Comment: I think I would do the IsNullOrEmpty checking in the first block, so it never even makes it into the list if it's empty.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It *looks* like you probably want something like:

```
_someDTOObject.Users = string.Join(",", Users.Split(',')
                                             .Select(x => x.Trim().ToUpper())
                                             .Distinct());
```

... but it's not clear to me why you're going through split/join/split to start with...

Note: if you're using .NET 3.5, you'll need an extra `ToArray` call after `Distinct`. You don't on .NET 4, as the set of `string.Join` overloads has been increased.

(As noted in StriplingWarrior's answer, this won't have a trailing comma. Did you *want* a trailing comma?)

Comment: Jon your answer looks to be correct looks like he is building some sort of comma delimited users list

Comment: Thanks - <<but it's not clear to me why you're going through split/join/split to start with...>> I am not sure either, that's why I asked because it didn't look right. I will go back and examine my requirements. Your LINQ answer works and thanks for the note on .NET 3.5 also.
How would you do this without LINQ (just curious)?

Comment: I didn't want the trailing comma (actually it doesn't matter), and I think thats why I had `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))` check in the second foreach loop

Comment: @VoodooChild: That wouldn't stop you from getting a trailing comma - look at your loop; if you have *any* non-empty strings, you'll *definitely* have a trailing comma. As for doing it without LINQ... um, I'd probably end up using a `Dictionary<string, whatever>` if I had to use .NET 2.0...

Answer (score 3):

This is a much cleaner way to *mostly* get the same result:

```
var distinctUsers = 
    (from user in Users.Split(new[]{','})
     select trimmedUpper = user.Trim().ToUpper())
    .Distinct()

_someDTOObject.Users = string.Join(",", distinctUsers);
```

However, this won't have a trailing ",", which may or may not be desirable. You may also want to examine why you need to end up with a comma-separated list in the first place. Is it possible that you'd be better off passing around a list of user names instead?

Answer (score 2):

This will take care of removing duplicated and empty names.

```
string Users = "bob, bill, james, frank, , bill"; 
var z = Users.Split( new char[] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x=> x.Trim().ToUpper()).Distinct().ToArray();  
var result = string.Join(",", z);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can be useful.

```
_someDTOObject.Users = Users.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(user => user.Trim().ToUpper()).Distinct().Aggregate((users, user) => users + "," + user);
```

Regards.